# gpiozero on a pi4?

Tags: gpio, python, pi-4, gpiozero

Working on getting some working samples setup for my son on his RPI4 so he can play with the GPIO's, breadboard, and some various pieces to use with the breadboard.  Right now we're trying to test out a RGB LED, and are using the gpiozero library in python3

Note that I did not install the gpiozero library, I was just playing with some code samples I found online to get it up and running for him quickly and realized the library came packaged with the PI OS already.  However, now I'm confused as to why it thinks it's not running on a RPI?  Looking at the docs it appears that gpiozero should run on all Pi's, but it has zero in the name, is this only compatible with a Pi zero?

This is what I'm running.  Note that this is a snippet of the full script, I reduced it to 2 lines to reproduce the error, but the error below lists it as line 10 from the file(10 = 2 in my sample below)

```
from gpiozero import RGBLED
led = RGBLED(red=18, green=23, blue=24)
```

And getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/pi.py", line 109, in pin
    pin = self.pins[n]
KeyError: 18

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "04_cheerlights.py", line 10, in <module>
    led = RGBLED(red=18, green=23, blue=24)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 124, 
in __call__
    self = super(GPIOMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py", 
line 901, in __init__
    for pin in (red, green, blue)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py", 
line 901, in <genexpr>
    for pin in (red, green, blue)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 124, 
in __call__
    self = super(GPIOMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py", 
line 414, in __init__
    pin, active_high, initial_value=None, pin_factory=pin_factory
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/output_devices.py", 
line 93, in __init__
    super(OutputDevice, self).__init__(pin, pin_factory=pin_factory)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 106, 
in __init__
    super(SourceMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/devices.py", line 521, 
in __init__
    pin = self.pin_factory.pin(pin)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/pi.py", line 111, 
in pin
    pin = self.pin_class(self, n)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/rpigpio.py", line 
132, in __init__
     GPIO.setup(self.number, GPIO.IN, self.GPIO_PULL_UPS[self._pull])
RuntimeError: Not running on a RPi!
```

Also, here's my OS version info

```
cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

uname

```
uname -a
Linux *hostname* 4.19.97-v7l+ #1294 SMP Thu Jan 30 13:21:14 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: the 2 lines of code that generate the error are included in the post.  What else are you looking for?

Comment: As an experiment try using a different backend

Comment: yeah, I get that they do nothing, however on my system they generate the error I am trying to fix, which makes the rest of the code irrelevant.

Comment: Joan, when you say use a different backend, what are you referring to by "backend"?

Comment: python3 myscript.py

Comment: The backend actually talks to the GPIO.  Typically it would be RPi.GPIO or pigpio.  Try setting a different pin factory.

Comment: $user3246693 , Welcome and nice to meet you. Ah, let me see.  I agree with you that two lines of code is just enough. More lines more trouble.

Comment: $user3246693, you might like to see how my two lines run: https://imgur.com/CVW6yfk. PS - I don't have any RGB LED. I just did a fake run. :) Cheers.

Comment: $user3246693, I skimmed the error message and found the last line interesting: "***RuntimeError: Not running on a RPi!***". Is your Rpi a fake one? :)

Comment: Is your OS fully updated? ‘sudo apt update‘ ‘sudo apt full-upgrade -y’ I suspect RPi.GPIO is out of date.

Comment: @Milliways they are (you can see it in the stack trace). gpiozero uses RPi.GPIO underneath (by default). As the author of gpiozero I'd agree this is the most likely issue.

Comment: It's a permissions thing.  Out of habbit I never run under default accounts, and my account I log in with is lacking some sort of permission that is needed to run that module and instead of a permissions issue it throws an error about not being a RPI.  Running the script as Pi or root works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't run as a limited user.  Need to run the script as root or the default Pi account and all is right with the world again.

Comment: Ah, out of habit newbie me never run bash python but always jail breaking Thonny.

Comment: Or add your limited user to the "gpio" group which, on Raspbian at least, permits access to the GPIO registers

Comment: Please mark the answer as the accepted one with a click on the tick on its left side. That prevents your Question from being shown as a unsolved Post to the community and saves them/us a lot of work.